# Removing grub after uninstalling ubuntu

Tags: windows-10

After deleting the partitions of ubuntu on my windows 10, I started to get this grub screen. I wanted to perform most of the solutions offered here but I don't have a windows installation disk because my windows 8 is built-in and i did an online windows 10 upgrade. please advise

Comment: Note: you didn't delete the Ubuntu's partitions *on your windows 10*. ;-)

Comment: no other partition could be deleted except my main ones. plus i couldn't access my ubuntu, so what does this say?

Comment: You should make a Windows 10 repair disk as soon as you get it working. Can you directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu or one time boot key? Delete /EFI/ubuntu folder from Windows
http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/09/05/how-to-delete-grub-files-from-a-boot-efi-partition-in-windows-10/
Remove Ubuntu from UEFI: Really UEFI boot menu edits
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu

Comment: I wanted to say that your Ubuntu's partitions weren't *inside* your Windows 10 partition. (Unless you were running Ubuntu inside a Virtual Machine, but it doesn't seem to be the case here.) They existed *side by side*.

Comment: Even i agree with oldfred . Please create a recovery media for your windows. Please think carefully before doing any such operations.

Answer (score 1):

You should login to Windows in the recovery mode(if needed using the installation disk - hopefully even Windows 8 should allow you to do so). Otherwise try to create a recovery media of Windows 10 after login into that.

Then at the command promot(Run as administrator)

```
bootrec /fixMbr
bootrec /fixboot
```

For more details please refer to [this](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows)

Comment: in the recovery mode, I have tried the command prompt and keyed in those commands but it said they were unrecongized. I then tried to do a system repair which also failed. then I did a system restore which failed as well. Lastly, I did a PC reset to the system only, but again it didn't work out

Comment: @HeshamAlbawani. Have you tried opening command prompt(run as administrator)and then 'cd c:\windows\system32\' and then run those commands from there?

Comment: yes and it responded that the command was not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: try 'bootsect' command with the same options

Comment: this is what i get :
bootsect {/help|/nt60|/nt52} {SYS|ALL|<DriveLetter>:} [/force] [/mbr]

Boot sector restoration tool

Bootsect.exe updates the master boot code for hard disk partitions in order to
switch between BOOTMGR and NTLDR.  You can use this tool to restore the boot
sector on your computer.

Run "bootsect /help" for detailed usage instructions

Comment: So that means you logged into Windows 10 using Windows 8 installation media. Your command should be 'bootset c:\mbr /mbr' but check it before running this command. This site is for help on Ubuntu - for other O/s and flavors of Linux - you need to make sure you understand the command/solution before applying.